# Regexp in TCL to parse out string prior to last matching character

Tags: regex, tcl

In a TCL script I have a objects with string values like:

```
ab_cde_12-3_xyz
def_5&6_hjk
zzz_1@234
```

I need to extract the substrings prior to (but not including) the last '_'.

I have tried :

```
regexp -all -inline {(.*)(?=_)} $my_string
```

But it gives extra garbage which I don't need.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Thanks,
Gert

Answer (score 4):

Ok, there are 3 ways to do that:

- Match everything until `_` followed by no other `_`:

  ```
  regexp {^(.*)_[^_]*$} $my_string -> data
  ```
- Replace the last part with an empty string:

  ```
  regsub {_[^_]*$} $my_string {}
  ```
- Get the substring of your string up until the last `_`

  ```
  string range $my_string 0 [string last _ $my_string]-1
  ```

  This only works if the string has an `_`, otherwise I suggest

  ```
  expr {[set pos [string last _ $my_string]] != -1
        ? [string range $my_string 0 ${pos}-1]
        : $my_string}
  ```

Comment: I like the `regsub`-based solution best.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
(.*)_[^_]*$
```

This is "everything up to a `_` followed by zero or more non-`_` characters followed by the end of the string."  This ensures that it is the *last* underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a regular expression for this: list operations will do fine:

```
set new [join [lrange [split $my_string _] 0 end-1] _]
```

Comment: why use list ops? string ops will just work fine: `string range $my_string 0 [string last _ $my_string]-1`; will only fail if there is no `_` in the string.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, nice. Better than my answer. I suggest you submit this as a separate answer